# How to export and then import a scene with Three JS?

Tags: import, export, three.js

I have a complex 3D scene builded with Three JS and a lot of Javascript code. I need to export this scene as one file and then use it on my site with a simple ThreeJS scene player.

I have tried ObjectExporter and SceneExporter. But still can not understand how to load this data back into ThreeJS environment.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: I made a map in Three.js using JSON and stored it to a file. All of the information from the map was stored there, so I wrote a function that would read it from the file.

Comment: Most likely you'll have to use OBJLoader to import your scene. I'm also on same issue like you, we'll see how we can work it out. Could you post your export code (using ObjectExporter, SceneExporter)?

Answer (score 4):

SceneExporter does not export the scene objects that are loaded through JSON
ObjectExporter can't exports texture

link scripts

```
ObjectExporter.js
GeometryExporter.js
BufferGeometryExporter.js
MaterialExporter.js

function exportScene(save, type) {
    exporter = new THREE.ObjectExporter;
    var obj = exporter.parse(scene);
    var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
    log(json);
}
```

save json to file ext .json
Library taken from https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/examples/js/exporters
Loader taken from https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/editor
default import in editor menu->file->import
I'm working on that to add the ability to export texture

Comment: And how to import scene in other file?