# How to export, import, seralize, deseralize a full scene in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to export a full Three.js scene and then store it and import it later. I expected this would be straight forward, something like:

```
// Create scene1 before hand

sceneJSON = scene1.toJSON();
sceneObj = THREE.JSONLoader.prototype.parse(sceneJSON);
scene2 = new THREE.Scene();
scene2.add(sceneObj);
```

This throws an error:

`three.js:18189 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Apparently the output from `scene1.toJSON();` is not what `THREE.JSONLoader.prototype.parse` is expecting.

I've put together a js fiddle to demonstrate this error here:

https://jsfiddle.net/kevzettler/d0fteot7/30/

This other question seems relevant but way out of date. The interfaces cited there are no longer in Three.js

[How to export and then import a scene with Three JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516961/how-to-export-and-then-import-a-scene-with-three-js)